# How to reshape a python vector when some elements are empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with values:

```
   A   B   C   D
0  1   2   3   2        
1  2   3   3   9        
2  5   3   6   6        
3  3       6   7       
4  6           7      
5  2
```

`df.shape` is 6x4, say

`df.iloc[:,1]` pulls out the B column, but `len(df.iloc[:,1])` is also = 6

How do I "reshape"   `df.iloc[:,1]`? Which function can I use so that the output is the length of the actual values in the column.

My expected output in this case is 3

Comment: You can try `df.iloc[:,1].notnull().sum()` to get 3.

Comment: Do you need `df.iloc[:,1].count()` ? Or for all columns `df.count()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this.

```
len([x for x in df.iloc[:,1] if x != ''])
```

Comment: This list creation is pretty expensive and not necessary. If you want to do something like this I recommend `sum(1 for x in df.iloc[: 1] if x!= '')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html). Just note that since your series originally contained `NaN` values and these are considered `float`, even after filtering your series will be `float`. You may wish to convert to `int` as a separate step.

```
# first convert dataframe to numeric
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# extract column
B = df.iloc[:, 1]

# filter to the last valid value
B_filtered = B[:B.last_valid_index()]

print(B_filtered)

0    2.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    6.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ah, @jpp - so it doesn't work... perhaps because B for me is an object? dtype: object

My B is in fact:

0    2018-08-02 00:00:00
1    2016-07-20 00:00:00
2    2015-09-14 00:00:00
3    2014-09-11 00:00:00
4                       
5                       
6                       
7                       
8                       
9                       
Name: EUR6m3m, dtype: object

and whilst list comprehension works to test len, I really want to concat this with another series of the same length. But, without the blanks. 

B_filtered returned the same as B

Comment: @JunaidMohammad, With Pandas you should convert numeric data to numeric series, e.g. `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`. Working with `object` dtype is not recommended as it does not permit vectorised computations.

Comment: @ jpp , understood. however, when I try the code, I get back a df of NaNs. I assume this is because my df contains dates and times? 

Which means im still left with an inability to filter B? 

unless I guess I use:
'B_filtered = B[:len([x for x in entrydates.iloc[:,1] if x != ''])]'

But id like to understand the object vs numeric issue I seem to have come across, thanks

Comment: I have no idea. Your question only has integers and blanks. I can't really advise further without a [mcve].

Comment: understood. Sometimes I think I simplify my questions too much. Ill keep digging or re-ask. Thank you for your help